# How to Create a Flat Button Style

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8, styles

In following with current design philosophy, I'd like to be able to create flat button style that I can apply any phone accent color to. Essentially I'd like this to look somewhat like a tile, with the flat theme and an icon as the button's content. How might I accomplish this? I do not need to use the HubTile or any sort of secondary tile in my application, this is just for use as a button to be themed in this way. It will simply navigate a user to another part of the application. I am not sure how to change the default style template for a button control to create such an effect? My end result would be to have four of these stylized buttons along the bottom of the screen, each with a different icon as the content which would be intuitive to a user as to what the button's click event will proceed in doing.

EDIT

Glass Button Style, that I would like to modify to Flat Button Style

```
<Style x:Key="GlassButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>

                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            </vsm:VisualState>

                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="glow" 
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" 
                                                              Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>

                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value=".55"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4">
                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="#7F000000" BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.507*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.493*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border Opacity="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="glow" Width="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <RadialGradientBrush>
                                            <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                <TransformGroup>
                                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.702" ScaleY="2.243"/>
                                                    <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                                    <TranslateTransform X="-0.368" Y="-0.152"/>
                                                </TransformGroup>
                                            </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#B28DBDFF" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#008DBDFF" Offset="1"/>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="shine" Width="Auto" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.494,0.889" StartPoint="0.494,0.028">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#99FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#33FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have tried to modify the `shine` Border at the bottom of the style to a single color (preferably a dark (possibly with an opacity of .7) grey that would nicely match the dark theme) but I still see effects of the glass button style, namely the top half of the button being lighter than the bottom. I believe the other changes I would like to do I can manage, such as removing corner radius of button style so that the button would be square and also the border around the button. Either way, any recommendations, tips, or advice would greatly help!

Comment: Any particular reason why it has to be a button, why not just a border with image inside, react to tap event and voila...? Add a tilt effect from Windows Phone toolkit for a complete Windows Phone experience? :)

Comment: That's a good point. My main reason was to use a style upon the button being Selected that I have from an existing 'Glass' button for the 'Flat' button. Would something like this be able to be used on a Border? I have added the style above (the same from the another question of mine you just commented on). I'd prefer to get away from the 'glass' effect and just use a flat, square, button (or border) to better match standard Windows Phone design.

Comment: see my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<Style x:Key="FlatButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Use it like this:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
        Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" 
        Height="80" Width="300" Margin="12,0"
        Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

And the result is this:

[image: Result - flat button]

Edit: Used TemplateBinding for the Border Margin property to remove the predefined spacing

Comment: Seems to work great. My only question is, when placed in a grid, there is spacing  between the end of the button and the edge of the grid. What property should I change to remove spacing so the button stretches to the edge of the grid? I set the margin to `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="-12"/>`, which seems to take care of the issue of removing the gap between the edge of the button and its grid. Is this the correct/best method?

Comment: @Matthew Remove Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" from border in the Style and add Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" instead. Then just use the Margin property of the Button to set whatever margin you may want. EDIT: I did it in the code above for you.

Comment: On one more note, I see in the style where the background can be changed when the button is pressed, but how might I change only the content image foreground (the icon) when the button is pressed?